# Are free SSL certificates secure?

Tags: https, security-certificate

How is it that some SSL certificates are free? What does that mean? Are they secure or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason why companies charge for SSL certificates is they put time and effort into creating the certificate and expect to be paid for their work (at a profit of course). But they don't *have* to charge if they don't want to just like any free provider of services can do. What matters with SSL certificates is whether the major browser makers recognize the certificate issuers as trustworthy or not. If they do the browser will display the site as secure just like it would from any other recognized provider. If they don't then any user attempting to access a web page secured by the unrecognized certificate will see a warning letting them know that the certificate is not recognized and warn them not to proceed.

So the real question is, "which free provides are recognized by the major browser makers as being authoritative"?

Comment: In other words, they are secure certificates, just not "verified" from an issuing certificate provider, since its a self-created certificate. Makes me wonder why the webserver itself cant verify the certificate. But then again, i guess they wouldnt make $$$ they way, would they?

Comment: It is your browser that determines the validity of the certificate that the server presents.  A self signed certificate will create a secure connection, but it won't validate the server is owned by the person who it claims to be, that is what the certificate authorities are for, and they charge for the process of verifying and certifying the certificates the server is presenting.

Comment: @Talvi: Good joke!... wait, that was a joke, right? The certificate is used to verify the identity of the server, amongst other things. Asking a certificate is like asking someone's ID: "What's your name? Joe Blow. Can you show me some ID? Sure." Then the guy takes a piece of paper, writes "Joe Blow" and gives it to you. There, here is my ID. So you look at it, and you say "Ah, all right. If it's on a piece of paper, it must be true... A server producing its own certificate is pretty much the same thing. "Are you the right server for my bank?" "Yes. These are not the droids you're looking for"

Comment: @Sylver  What alternative do you think there is?  It's just a matter of where you're placing your trust:  "What's your name? Joe Blow.  Can you show me some ID? Sure."  The guy introduces his friend, Very Sign, who takes a bit of paper, writes "Joe Blow" and gives it to you.  There, here is my ID. So you look at it, and you say "Ah, all right. If it's on a piece of paper, it must be true...  The identification properties of a certificate are really just a side benefit of the encryption technique.  Go and check who signs the certificate for https://www.verisign.com

Comment: @robert: Exactly, except that Veri Sign is not Joe Blow's friend. Verisign is a regulated company whose main business is to attest the identity of people. A passport or an ID card is just a fancy piece of printing on fancy paper, but we accept it because we believe that it was issued by a reliable agency which checked the identity of the applicant, because there are serious penalties for counterfeit and because they are not easy to fake in the first place. To get a certificate from Verisign, they will first check that you are legit. ...

Comment: ..This is why browsers will accept a cert from Verisign and will warn the user if you issue your own certs.

Comment: @Sylver Verisign is regulated?  By who?  If they hand out an SSL certificate so to someone who doesn't own the domain in question what law have they broken?  And Verisign is just one of hundreds of certificate providers that browser will accept by default, the criteria for getting on that list is not to conform to some third party process standard or to have a great security track record but to be able to afford to pay the browser vendor to get your certificate included in the browser release.

Comment: @Sylver   Accepting a certificate issued by a CA that is not on the list included with the browser is NO LESS SECURE than accepting one that is on the list, this is not because self signed and alternative CA providers are massively secure, but because certificates issued by providers that are on the list are not as secure as you seem to think they are, they do not have any magic security properties, they just have the ability to pay to get themselves on a list.

Comment: @Sylver Kind of joke, kind of not. Since a websites owner must have access and authorization to install a certificate, or change one... a fake certificate would require someone to have full access to that website to install it.. in which case SSL authentication isn't going to help you. (the exploiter already has full website access, so SSL is a moot point.)

Comment: @Robert: Verisign is regulated in various ways. First it's a listed company on the NASDAQ, second, it has a contract with the Department of commerce for it's DNS activities as well as with ICANN. It's a lot more regulated than some guy operating a LLC somewhere.

Comment: @Talvi: To create a SSL cert, you need access to a hosting account. To get a SSL cert from Verisign, you need to provide ID and paperwork to Verisign and receive approval, in addition to having access to an hosting account. If you can't see there is a difference here, sorry, there is nothing much I can tell you.

Comment: @Sylver None of that is regulation, all of that is just market pressure, and I'm not aware of any paperwork that has to be provided to Verisign to get a certificate or how that increases security.  And Verisign is just one of about 100 root CA certificate included in (for example) Firefox.  If you know and trust the 'guy operating a LLC somewhere' why would his certificate be any less secure than any of those you get by default.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSL_certificates_for_web_servers) for a good comparison of SSL services. It looks like [startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) has a free SSL cert service which is recognized by IE, FF and Safari.

I suspect there are other similar services around. The main issue is to find providers which are supported by modern browsers. Having a browser warn the user that the certificate is not reliable is worse than not having a certificate at all, from the POV of conversion & sales.

Comment: StartCom certificates are no longer trusted by major browsers: [StartSSL certificate gives SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE in Firefox and ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/startssl-certificate-gives-sec-error-revoked-certificate-in-firefox-and-err-cert)

Comment: The Wikipedia website is deleted. Can you add a new one there?

Answer (score 0):

[Public Key Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) depends on a [Trusted Third Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_third_party) that will verify and then can endorse your identitiy.

When you pay a major certificate authority like Verisign for a certificate, you are paying for their reputation as a reputable and trusted third party that can endorse the validity of your identity and your certificate.  From a practical standpoint, that means that major browsers come pre-configured to trust certificates signed by those authorities.

I can create a certificate for you for free, but it will be relatively worthless, because nobody knows who I am and so my endorsement doesn't give them any confidence.

Answer (score 0):

Even major certificate authorities like verisign,globalsign,COMODO give a free trail period version of SSL certificate because they give us the chance for trusting and valuing their product.